# Can I skip part III in Dummit and Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, advice, reference-works

> I am reading Abstract Algebra by Dummit anfd Foote. I have already taken an introductory course in linear algebra, mostly at the level of [Strang's MIT OCW Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8). My question is: Can I skip 'Part III: Modules and Vector spaces' and jump directly to chapter 13: Field Theory in Dummit and Foote? Will that be harmful?

(Note that I am planning to cover Part I up to 5.3 and Part II up to 9.5, as suggested in preface of D&F. )

Comment: General advice: Feel free to jump around a book however you like, as long as you keep eyes wide open. If you get stuck somewhere, be ready to do an index search or a table of contents search to tell you where you must jump back to, earlier in the book, to teach what you need to get unstuck.

Comment: You'll probably need to know about more general modules at some point, but it may not be necessary for doing field theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what your goal is. If you want to get to the culmination of a classical abstract algebra class, Galois theory and the solvability of the quintic, you will not be missing much if any.

If you plan to go on to graduate study (even in group theory or field theory!), or even read through the rest of D&F, then you will in all likeliness encounter material that build on PID modules.

However there is no harm in skipping part III for the time being. A lot of the abstract module business is more abstract than you have encountered so far and will benefit from having a motivation to read it.

Also make sure that you do not just read the chapter text but also look at the exercises. The standard result and applications of the theory -- matrix normal forms and finding particular conjugating matrices -- are hidden in the exercises of these chapters.

(Basis for my remarks: I have taught multiple times a first-year graduate class on this material, using D&F)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Comment: If I want to do part 3, would you even reccomend doing the field theory chapter first to get some more experience, and then doing chapters 10-12? (I don't really know Linear Algebra, I just remember the very basic things from a 2000-level course)

Comment: @Ovi, Sorry for late comment. I am noe following Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra, and it is just awesome. I am actually understanding things, and it is not extreme workload, so I love learning abstract algebra. Gallian goes straight from Rings to Fields. A good companion is [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu5cg_Jd9XSJL_CHUskgkGw/playlists), here that person covers groups, rings, fields and vector spaces in very accessible manner. You may also try Benedict Gross' Abstract Algebra lectures on youtube. They are a bit advanced, but super fun.

Comment: @Silent Thanks! Yes Gallian is great, so much better than Dummit and Foote. I ended up doing modules and vector spaces before fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine doing this. The proofs in field theory mostly use more basic notions from linear algebra. So if you feel comfortable with vector spaces and linear transformations, then this is ok. (In fact, the graduate level abstract algebra sequence I am taking is doing this)